# Preserve dot notation when editing HOCON file

Tags: python, python-3.x, hocon

I'm creating a hocon conf file using pyhocon.(https://github.com/chimpler/pyhocon).

I'm trying to build the hocon file by using a standard hocon file, updating the necessary values and upload the updated file.

```
deployment {
      proxy {
        // Name has to be replaced with the name of the project
        cluster.TEST {
          property1 = [a_list]
          property2.host = "hostname"
        }
      }
    }
```

I'm able to update values using pyhocon:

```
from pyhocon import ConfigFactory


conf = ConfigFactory.parse_string(hocon_file_template)
host = "something-TEST.trial.com"
conf.put('deployment.proxy.cluster.TEST.property2.host', host)
new = HOCONConverter.convert(conf, "hocon")
```

However, the converted file gets rid of the dot notation and outputs:

```
deployment {
      proxy {
        // Name has to be replaced with the name of the project
        cluster {
         TEST {
                 property1 = [a_list]
                 property2.host = "hostname"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

How do I maintain the attributes in dot notation?

Comment: I suspect the parser doesn't preserve that information, so it's not possible.

Comment: I'm surprised it put `property2.host` in the output.

Comment: Try using the `compact=True` argument to `convert()`